# Converted mp4 from gif didn't shows in web browser

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert animated GIFs to MP4 files using ffmpeg. Only this convert GIF to MP4:

```
  exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $destinationPath . $filename . ' -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" ' . $destinationPath . $newFilename);
```

And I can play it in my pc when download it from server, but it's didn't want to pay in browser. Browser returns me this error:
[image]

After that GIF to MP4 converor I get one image for thumbnail image and that is works fine:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i " . $destinationPath . $video . ".mp4 -ss  00:00:01.000 -vframes 1 ".storage_path().$folderNameThumb."/media.png");
```

and it's shows me a valid frame of GIF. Can anybody help me how to fix this problem with video?

```
ffprobe output
ffprobe version 2.8.13 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)
configuration:
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
```

Here is what I get from one MP4 file (run ffprobe filename.mp4):

```
 Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
Duration: 00:00:02.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 593 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 500x312 [SAR 1:1 DAR 125:78], 589 kb/s, 8.33 fps, 8.33 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Because I use Laravel this is method for return media:

```
public function getGifImage(Media $media)
{
    $path = storage_path() . '/uploads/gif/' . $media->content;
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        return response()->download($path, null, [], null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `-movflags +faststart` to the first command just before the output filename.

Comment: Sorry, my fault .. I paste test example that I last find. Now is correct one. Sorry. With add "-movflags +faststart" it's looks the same

Comment: Show the readout of `ffprobe output`

Comment: can you explain to me what to do, I didn't understand :(

Comment: you think this which I add in the end of post?

Comment: Run `ffprobe file.mp4` - replace with output file name

Comment: Just update post with that data which I get as response.

Comment: You need a binary with libx264 linked.

Comment: Can you explain how to and what to link?

Comment: Use a git build from https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: It works same as before

Comment: Add -report and run. Share report.

Comment: Might have something to do with how you're delivering the file through PHP.  Can you show that code?

Comment: @UltrasoundJelly I add return code to get that video

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the file on your computer and click to open in your browser?

Comment: We try @UltrasoundJelly but we get the same results and image.

Comment: try forcing h264 codec by adding:
`-c:v h264 -strict -2`

Comment: @StojanKukrika Show the `-report` as requested by Mulvya using the new `ffmpeg` you downloaded. Without it we can only provided guesses and not answers.

Comment: @Mulvya your link helps! It's working now! If you want, make answer to I mark it as future generations :) TNX a lot @Mulvya!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browsers, at this time, can only decode H.264 video within MP4s. Your ffmpeg binary does not have libx264 linked, so it's defaulting to the internal MPEG-4 Part 2 video codec.

Get a recent git binary with libx264 for your platform from

Linux: http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Windows: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Mac OS X: http://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/ , 
               http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/